# Identityserver4 sso between resource owner client and implicit client

Tags: authentication, .net-core, identityserver4

We have two clients to our STS (Identityserver4).

- ClientA (SPA) using resource owner flow (enter user/password in the SPA)
- ClientB (MVC) using implicit flow (login using Identityserver GUI)

**Question**: How can we implement SSO between ClientA and ClientB?

Can we use the accesstoken from ClientA to do a SSO when redirecting from ClientA to ClientB? What about from ClientB to ClientA. Should we avoid using cookie auth on ClientB?

Comment: Please share how you have defined both clients in IdentityServer4 along with how you configured IdentityServer4 in the MVC startup class.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer itself provides SSO out of the box.

You should be using implicit for your SPA client. ( Where you let IDM know about the client by looking at the cors origin and share the access token as per the scope requests, id token as per the user credentials , if profile is included )

MVC client depending on the trust whether the client can keep the password safely you should be choosing the Client credentials/ Resource owner grant (you get sub in the token).

Most of the cases MVC client will be choosing the Hybrid grant.

Once you have setup the clients with Idm server, then its matter of sharing the id token and cookies on the browser. Access token as per the scopes requested.

Comment: Well, the problem goes away if we go with implicit flow for our SPA. Having resource owner flow gives us a better UX.